# How to change config file of nginx runing via docker

Tags: nginx, docker

I have installed sharelatex from this image  https://github.com/sharelatex/sharelatex-docker-image via docker on Windows 7 with this command line

```
 $ docker run -d --name sharemongo mongo:latest
    $ docker run -d --name shareredis redis:latest
    $ docker run -d -P -p 80:80 -v /opt/sharelatex --env SHARELATEX_MONGO_URL=mongodb://mongo/sharelatex --end SHARELATEX_REDIS_HOST=redis --link sharemongo:mongo --link shareredis:redis --name sharelatex sharelatex/sharelatex
    and it seems to work
```

It could run. But i have  problem with upload a larger file (>2mb) . One person told me that just add this line into config file nginx

```
client_max_body_size 8m;
```

But i don't know how to change the config file in  nginx that already running via docker.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can either fork out/edit the [nginx.conf](https://github.com/sharelatex/sharelatex-docker-image/blob/master/nginx/nginx.conf) in the repo you have cloned or you can point the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/sharelatex/sharelatex-docker-image/blob/master/Dockerfile#L33) to the path of your custom nginx.conf.

Comment: yes. But i can't build image it from source code that i clone from Dockerfile because it has another error with install inside code. But install automatic with command that i mentioned above is ok, i do't know why

Comment: Can you update your question with the error message?